# how to select drop down value from .cs  and assign in javascript 

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#theSelect").toggle(0);
    $("#activate").click(activate)
})

function activate(e) 
{
    $("#theSelect").toggle((e.target.checked));

    if (!e.target.checked) 
    { // reset selection
        $("#theSelect option[value='--Select--']").attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
}
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="theSelect">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="foo">foo</option>
                <option value="bar">bar</option>
            </select>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="activate" /> Activate
         </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have one page called (staff-insert-update.aspx). The above code works fine for the insert mode where intially during the checkbox is selected[--select value  comes]
  but in edit mode if the user a value checked in the  checkbox  and his corresponding value  should be shown in the  drop down instead of  a  default  value as  we  do  for   the insert  mode.  Now in  edit mode  the user  has  to get his  selected  value  when this checkbox  in checked  in .cs  file  of  asp.net

looking for this  solution from past 1  day. Could not find  solution how  to solve it 
 any help  on this would be  great

thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got your question right.
But I took a shot.Try this out.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#activate").val().length == 0){
        $("#theSelect").toggle(0);
    }else{
     $("#theSelect").val(($("#activate").val()));
    }
    $("#activate").click(activate) 
}) 

function activate(e)  
{ 
    $("#theSelect").toggle((e.target.value.length>0)); 

    if (!e.target.checked)  
    { // reset selection 
        $("#theSelect option[value='--Select--']").attr('selected', 'selected'); 
    }else{
     $("#theSelect").val(($("#activate").val()));
}   
} 
</script> 
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td> 
            <select id="theSelect"> 
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option> 
                <option value="foo">foo</option> 
                <option value="bar">bar</option> 
            </select> 
        </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
         <td> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="activate" checked='checked' value='bar'
            /> Activate 
         </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: hey thanks  for the replay  but even in   upadate  mode  if  my  dropddown had a value selected  it is not showing that value instead  of that it  is  showing   the default select value which  should not happen